# Login check with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have an ajax function in my index file:

```
var xmlhttp;
function loadocget(url, func)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = func;
         xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
}

function verifyLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var formdata = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    loadocget("verify.php?" + formdata, function ()
    {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
         {
             var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
             if (result != "true"){
                document.getElementById("ack").innerHTML = "<p>Your username or password is invalid</p>";
             });
          }
     }
}
```

And a form also in my index file:

```
<div id="ack"></div>
<form action="member.php" method="post" onsubmit="return verifyLogin();" name="login-form" id="login-form">
     <div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Username: </label>
              <input name="username" id="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" required/>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Password: </label>
              <input name="password" id="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" id="login-submit" name="login-submit" value="Sign In" />
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="signup-button" name="signup-button" value="Sign Up"/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <div id="forgot" class="link-div"><p style="cursor: pointer;">Forgot your username or password?</p></div>
         </div>
</form>
```

And a verify.php file to check username and password:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
include_once 'connectDB.php';
$Table = "users";
$temp = $_GET['password'];
$password = md5($username . $temp);
$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $Table WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($SQLstring, $DBConnect);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo false;
} else {
    echo true;
}
?>
```

When I debug these codes with firebug, I could see the warning message appeared, but the form still took user to the member.php page. Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is checking the response for the character string `"true"`, but your PHP code is sending the boolean `true` or `false`. When you echo these, `true` becomes `1` and false is an empty string.

Change it to:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "false";
} else {
    echo "true";
}
```

You also need to modify `verifyLogin` so that it prevents normal form submission (by returning `false`). After it gets a successful response it can submit the form for real.

```
function verifyLogin() {
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var formdata = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password;
    loadocget("verify.php?" + formdata, function ()
    {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
         {
             var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
             if (result != "true"){
                document.getElementById("ack").innerHTML = "<p>Your username or password is invalid</p>";
             } else {
                document.getElementById("login-form").submit();
             }
          }
     }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried your solution, but it didnt work. The index page still took me to member.php page.

Comment: Make sure your script doesn't print anything other than those two `echo` statements. Get rid of the `?>` line -- there might be a newline after it.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sticking with me. Sadly, I just applied your suggestion, and it still didnt work.

Comment: You weren't preventing normal form submission. I've updated the answer to show how to do this in your Javascript.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I did include onsubmit="return verifyLogin();" in my form tag. Isnt that supposed to prevent my form from submitting if verifyLogin returns false?

Comment: Yes, it does. But your version of `verifyLogin` doesn't return false -- it has no `return` statement at all. Also, remember that AJAX is asynchronous, so it can't return something from the AJAX call.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explaination. We always have to return either false or true from an ajax func call not a variable that has value of true or false, correct? So the last return line in your answer is preventing form submission, correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: You can only send strings over the network. But you can use JSON to encode other types of values in strings.